# How do I make my instagram bot move through pictures and like each one?

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui

For my first  project on automation, I am working on a bot that can go to a hashtag on instagram and like each pictures as it iterates through them. The bot can do what is mentioned above except like each pictures as it iterates. I need help figuring this out.

i

```
import pyautogui,time
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False

pyautogui.moveTo(608, 431,duration=0.1) #Goes moves cursor to search bar
pyautogui.click(608, 43) # clicks on search bar
pyautogui.typewrite("http://instagram.com") #types in web address 
pyautogui.typewrite(["enter"]) #activates enter key


pyautogui.moveTo(641, 96,duration=0.1) #moves cursor to instagram search bar
pyautogui.click(641, 96) #clicks on search bar
pyautogui.typewrite("#cats")# types in hashtag 
pyautogui.moveTo(652, 225,duration=0.1) #moves cursor to hashtag suggestion
time.sleep(1);pyautogui.click(652, 225)#clicks on hashtag suggestion

#Clicks on picture
pyautogui.moveTo(348, 564,duration=0.1) #moves cursor on picture
time.sleep(1);pyautogui.click() #Clicks on picture
time.sleep(1);pyautogui.moveTo(1170, 451) #moves cursor to the right arrow on picture  
for i in range(4): #clicks on pictures by iterating a certain number of times
    pyautogui.click(1170, 451)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following

```
for i in range(4):

    time.sleep(5)
    pyautogui.moveTo(xRes/2, yRes/2, duration=0.5)
    pyautogui.doubleClick()
```

`xRes` and `yRes` refers to the monitor resolution, and like the image by double clicking. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much. would I have to import any package related to the screen resolution?

Comment: You can get the resolution  with `pyautogui.size()`